# How to use a runtime variable in a Docker task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build and push a docker image using a azure devops pipeline but I cannot manage to use a matrix variable in the docker task. I wrote the following yaml:

```yaml
trigger:
  - main
variables:
  tag: "$(Build.BuildId)"
  repository: rs/sustain_api
  buildConfiguration: Release

jobs:
  - job: docker
    pool: DockerLinux
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dev:
          environment: DEV
          acrConnection: CDM1DREPACR002
        prd:
          environment: PRD
          acrConnection: CDM1PREPACR002
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        displayName: get files
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: "Login to $(environment) ACR"
        inputs:
          command: login
          containerRegistry: "$(acrConnection)"
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: "Build image and push $(tag)"
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          containerRegistry: "$(acrConnection)"
          repository: "$(repository)"
          Dockerfile: "**/Dockerfile"
          tags: "$(Tag)"
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: "Logout from $(environment) ACR"
        inputs:
          command: logout
          containerRegistry: "$(acrConnection)"
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        condition: eq(variables.environment, 'PRD')
        displayName: "Publish Artifact: sustain-api"
        inputs:
          ArtifactName: sustain-api
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job docker: Step Docker1 input containerRegistry references service connection $(acrConnection) which could not be found.

Which means that the variable has not been interpreted. Anything I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to "**`containerRegistry: ${{ variables.acrConnection }}`**".

Because:

- The service connection needs to be evaluated at the compile time rather than runtime.
- The macro syntax variables (**`$(var)`**) get processed during runtime.
- The template expression variables (**`${{ variables.var }}`**) get processed at compile time.

So, you cannot use the runtime expression to reference the service connection name, instead, you should use the compile time expression.

For more details, see "[**Understand variable syntax**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)".